# The Reset Button Does what the Calculate button does

Tags: c++, events, button, event-handling, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets and I've tried separating the two buttons' sizers but when I click them both, they still yield the same result. Look at the header and cpp code. I need help. Been here for an hour. Thanks :(

HEADER:

```
#include <vector>
#include <wx/wx.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;
class determinantsFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    determinantsFrame();
    virtual ~determinantsFrame();

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent &event);
    void OnCalculateClick(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnReset(wxCommandEvent &event);
    double determinant(double matrix[MAX][MAX], int order);

private:
    wxPanel *MainPanel;
    wxButton *Enter;
    wxButton *Reset;
    wxMenu *fileMenu;
    wxMenu *helpMenu;
    wxMenuBar *menuBar;
    wxTextEntryDialog *td;
    wxString str;
    //vector<double> value;

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

CPP:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "determinantsFrame.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(determinantsFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, determinantsFrame::OnAbout)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, determinantsFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_CLOSE(determinantsFrame::OnClose)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_ANY, determinantsFrame::OnCalculateClick)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_ANY, determinantsFrame::OnReset)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

int n;
wxTextCtrl *numbers[100][100];

void determinantsFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent &event)
{
    exit(1);
}

void determinantsFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxString msg;
    msg.Printf(wxT("Hello and welcome to %s"), wxVERSION_STRING);
    wxMessageBox(msg, wxT("About Determinants Calculator"));
}

void determinantsFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    Close();
}

determinantsFrame::~determinantsFrame()
{
    Destroy();
}

determinantsFrame::determinantsFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Determinants Calculator"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
{
    wxStaticBoxSizer *matrix;
    wxFlexGridSizer *cells;
    wxBoxSizer *subBox;
    wxBoxSizer *mainBox;

    fileMenu = new wxMenu;
    helpMenu = new wxMenu;
    menuBar = new wxMenuBar();

    helpMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, wxT("&About"), wxT("Show about dialog"));
    fileMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, wxT("&Exit"), wxT("Quit this program"));

    menuBar->Append(fileMenu, wxT("&File"));
    menuBar->Append(helpMenu, wxT("&Help"));

    td = new wxTextEntryDialog(this, wxT("Enter the number of dimensions: "), wxGetTextFromUserPromptStr, wxT("2"));
    td->ShowModal();
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    str = td->GetValue();
    n = wxAtoi(str);

    mainBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    MainPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    matrix = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL, MainPanel, "Matrix: ");
    cells = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, n, 0, 0);
    subBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            numbers[i][j] = new wxTextCtrl(MainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(40,20), 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TextCtrl"));
            cells->Add(numbers[i][j], 0, wxALL | wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
        }

    matrix->Add(cells, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2);
    subBox->Add(matrix, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);

    wxBoxSizer *enb = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *rnb = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *bc = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    Enter = new wxButton(MainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Calculate"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    Reset = new wxButton(MainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Reset"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    enb->Add(Enter, 1, wxALL |wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    rnb->Add(Reset, 1, wxALL |wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    bc->Add(enb, 0, wxALL | wxEXPAND);
    bc->Add(rnb, 0, wxALL | wxEXPAND);
    subBox->Add(bc, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);
    MainPanel->SetSizer(subBox);
    mainBox->Add(MainPanel);
    mainBox->Fit(this);
    this->SetSizer(mainBox);
    CentreOnScreen();
}

void determinantsFrame::OnReset(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            numbers[i][j]->SetLabelText(wxEmptyString);
}

void determinantsFrame::OnCalculateClick(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    double elem[MAX][MAX], det;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            elem[i][j] = static_cast<double>(wxAtoi(numbers[i][j]->GetValue()));

    det = determinant(elem, n);
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format(wxT("%.2f"),det));
}

double determinantsFrame::determinant(double matrix[MAX][MAX], int order)
{
    double det = 0, temp[MAX][MAX]; int row, col;

    if (order == 1)
        return matrix[0][0];
    else if (order == 2)
        return ((matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]));
    else
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < order; r++)
        {
            col = 0; row = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < order; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < order; j++)
                {
                    if (j == r)
                        continue;

                    temp[row][col] = matrix[i][j];
                    col++;

                    if (col == order - 1)
                        col = 0;
                }
                row++;
            }
            det = det + (matrix[0][r] * pow(-1, r) * determinant(temp, order - 1));
        }
        return det;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert on wxwidgets, but the control id `wxID_ANY` looks suspicious - you probably want unique ids for the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the ID's you assigned to the buttons which is wxID_ANY to both and also your message map in the CPP file.

```
EVT_BUTTON(wxID_ANY, determinantsFrame::OnCalculateClick)
EVT_BUTTON(wxID_ANY, determinantsFrame::OnReset)
```

As the message map of wxID_ANY is triggered it is first processed by OnCalculateClick and therefore the Reset button does the same as the Calculate button. My bet is if you switch those two lines, both buttons would behave as the Reset button.